Why does updating the profile pic not work well?
Whenever I change a user's profile picture, it reverts to the default user picture after refreshing the page. This happens every time, making it seem like the new profile picture isn't being saved properly. It could be due to the new image URL not being stored correctly in the database or the application not retrieving the updated URL when the page reloads. To fix this, I need to ensure that the new profile picture URL is correctly saved and fetched from the database every time the page loads.
html :
<img [src]="profileImageUrl || 'assets/images/user.png'" alt="Profile" class="rounded-circle" style="size: 130%;" (click)="triggerFileInput()">

ts :
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  profileImageUrl: string | null = null;
  private storage = getStorage();

  private readonly DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMAGE_URL = 'assets/images/user.png';
  
  
  triggerFileInput() {
    this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
  }

  onFileSelected(event: Event) {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      const file = input.files[0];
      
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        this.profileImageUrl = e.target.result; 
        this.uploadProfileImage(file);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
  
  uploadProfileImage(file: File) {
    const userId = this.authService.getUserId();
    if (userId) {
      const storageRef = ref(this.storage, `profileImages/${userId}/${file.name}`);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);     
      uploadTask.on(
        'state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
          
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            this.profileImageUrl = downloadURL;
            this.authService.updateProfileImageUrl(downloadURL);
            this.saveProfileImage(downloadURL);  
          });
        }
      );
    } 
  }      


  ngOnInit() {
    const userId = this.authService.getUserId();
    if (userId) {
      this.loadProfileImage(userId);
    } 
  }
  

  loadProfileImage(userId: string | null) {
    if (userId) {
      const storageRef = ref(this.storage, `profileImages/${userId}/profile.jpg`);
      getDownloadURL(storageRef)
        .then(url => {
          this.profileImageUrl = url;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.profileImageUrl = this.DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMAGE_URL;
        });
    } else {
      this.profileImageUrl = this.DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMAGE_URL;
    }
  }
  



  saveProfileImage(imageUrl: string) {
    const userId = this.authService.getUserId(); 
    if (userId) {
      const key = `profileImageUrl_${userId}`;
      localStorage.setItem(key, imageUrl);
    }
  }
    }

authservice.ts :
updateProfileImageUrl(imageUrl: string): Promise<void> {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  if (user) {
    return updateProfile(user, { photoURL: imageUrl })
  } else {
    return Promise.reject('No user is currently logged in.');
  }
}


getUserId(): string | null {
  const user = this.firebaseAuth.currentUser;
  return user ? user.uid : null;
}


you should include more code... but be aware that you're using some local client-side paths.  Ex: this.saveProfileImage(this.profileImageUrl!);  which may or may not run after the getDownloadURL().... this.saveProfileImage bit...

It looks to me as if the component is used for every image.
The method "saveProfileImage" somehow saves the image with the AuthService.
This AuthService is also used in "loadProfileImage" to load the latest image per event.
If you now have this AuthService provide in root, all ImageComponents use the same instance and are notified among themselves.
You would have to add the service to the provider of the ImageComponent if this is the problem.
That would be my suggestion based on the showed code.

i changed the code , u can have a look at it and tell me if there is anything i need to adjust , btw I added this to @component : providers: [AuthService]

Firstly, ensure that when you updating the profile pic, it is correctly stroing against the respective unique id(user id) of the user.
check the same in the save scenario also.
While when you retrieving the profile pic to dispaly, you shoould pass the unique id(user id) to get the profile pic, so each user will have their respective unique id's and will get their profile pics against their id's.
I hope this would help in some way..

i changed the code , u can have a look at it and tell me if there is anything i need to adjust
